# how to call logout in polymer 2.0

Tags: polymer, polymer-2.x

I am trying to call rest api (written in Spring Boot), using below tag in my client application that is using polymer 2.0:

```
<a class="white-color" href="/app/user/logout">Logout </a>
```

But the chrome browser only shows the below url and does not visit the page.

```
http://localhost:8080/app/user/logout
```

Then I have to press Enter, to call logout rest service. Can you please guide me as why logout anchor is not working without pressing ENTER key?

If i add  target="_blank" in above anchor tag as shown below,

```
 <a class="white-color" href="/app/user/logout" target="_blank">Logout </a>
```

then on click, new browser page opens, rest api is called and everything works fine.

Comment: You are facing problem because of the shell. As Polymer is SPA it does not load/reload pages. Polymer on route change expects the route to be present in it's shell and then tries to simply change the view (which is not the case for you). In your route handler function you should specifically handle this case.

Comment: Can you please guide me about how to write route handler function or share simple example of the solution?

Comment: Are you using starter app ?

Comment: Yes, I am using starter app.

Comment: I am able to call logout rest api successfully using on-click event on <a>. Can you tell me any function in polymer, that can refresh my current page. In this way, the authentication shall fail and user shall be directed to login screen developed by some third party.

Comment: you can use window's `location.reload()`

Comment: Thanks! Problem solved.